# Is it possible to display vega/vega-lite bar based on period time column?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I was wonder if it is possible to create a vega/vega-lite visualization , based on time periodic columns.
For example , assume that i would like to display a graph of athletics results in a bar/other visualization.

[rio-2016-athletics](https://www.bbc.com/sport/olympics/rio-2016/results/sports/athletics/mens-800m)

I have tried to make some changes to simple bar chart bellow.
I have edited only the "amount" column in order to display time-period results:

```
 "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "1", "amount": 1:42.15},
        {"category": "2", "amount": 1:42.61},
        {"category": "3", "amount": 1:42.93},
        {"category": "4", "amount": 1:43.41}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I got the following error message:
[Error] Unexpected token : in JSON at position 208 and line 12

Can one advise how to display time periodic column IN THE FORMAT THAT I AM LOOKING FOR (mm:ss.ms)

The original code was:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "1", "amount": 42.15},
        {"category": "2", "amount": 42.61},
        {"category": "3", "amount": 42.93},
        {"category": "4", "amount": 43.41}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale" },
    { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale" }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "datum === tooltip", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that you have created invalid JSON: your timestamps need to be quoted. That is, replace `1:42.15` with `"1:42.15"`.

As for parsing the dates, this is easiest to do in Vega-Lite. You can use the [Data Format](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html#format) value to control how your date strings are interpreted. For example ([online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghqA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uJhsJAMYKEDmA9gE4CeZkAjJADRRYAWxb4AdvG49kAFgBMAOh4BWSAF9+VamnqNWnbvIFDREqal5ylANj6bt1Wg3jN2XSwGYTkEWMnS1ooAnN4OOhDO+u7csj5+5oGynoqy9o4QALpaOpAAZuzCCGS0AA6wbMSEJb5mAZZwrsgA5ACkALLIrQDKiq0AMs0a6lThUEVsANbcpSwAlgE5UITidCzQC0wljpAAHjV5c4S40NwuboaCkPAcpdWW7BvieBpLEJAeuofHp5YJi1B4HNhIQAKriOYWcYLfCuYhVNbiaDEYRzXC4OYIlhI0hXG53biuYSzNgvEYQEbqIA)):

```
{
  "data": {
      "values": [
        {"category": "1", "amount": "1:42.15"},
        {"category": "2", "amount": "1:42.61"},
        {"category": "3", "amount": "1:42.93"},
        {"category": "4", "amount": "1:43.41"}
      ],
      "format": {"parse": {"amount": "date:'%M:%S.%L'"}}
  },
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "category", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "amount", "timeUnit": "minutessecondsmilliseconds", "type": "temporal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

If you're interested in how this translates to Vega, you can click the "Compiled Vega" tab in the above editor link.

Comment: Hello , why categories 1, 2 and 3 has such low value which is not represent the real value in the amount column.

Comment: The axis values are represented in milliseconds (vega-lite doesn't support centiseconds). 1:42.061, 1:42.041, and 1:42.015 are drawn in the correct place. The auto-determined axis labels are not particularly helpful here, though.

Comment: I changed the graph from "point" to "bar" but the results doesnt look like a simple bar graph.
The result is a small line at the top of the bar.
Also "y" axis should start from zero but its not.
By the way , why the "timeUnit" type is "temporal" ? 
I was tring to change the "y" "type" from "temporal" to "quantitative"
but for some reason it totaly changed the timeunit display on y axis

Comment: I will be happy to get a feedback regarding my last question

Comment: Short answer: Vega-Lite has no concept of time periods, only of time stamps. The zero-point for a timestamp is not well defined, so a bar mark is not a good fit for temporal data. If you want a longer answer with information about how to work around this limitation, please submit a new question.