# Work around to display vega-lite graph based on period time column?

Tags: vega-lite

I am asking this question as a follow-up to :
[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787286/is-it-possible-to-display-vega-vega-lite-bar-based-on-period-time-column)

The basic requirement is very simple:
To display sport competition results on a graph, based on human readable time period.
For example top 8 Men's 800m , from Rio 2016.

```
Rank    Name                    Time
1   David Lekuta Rudisha        1:42.15 
2   Taoufik Makhloufi       1:42.61 
3   Clayton Murphy          1:42.93 
4   Pierre-Ambroise Bosse       1:43.41 
5   Ferguson Cheruiyot Rotich   1:43.55 
6   Marcin Lewandowski      1:44.20 
7   Alfred Kipketer         1:46.02 
8   Boris Berian            1:46.15
```

There were some issues such as : 
The zero-point for a timestamp is not well defined, so a bar mark is not a good fit 
for temporal data.

I will appreciate any workaround to display to display time-period results to solve such a problem.

Thanks
Yoav

Answer (score 0):

Vega-lite does not have any native data type to represent time periods, it only has a data type representing timestamps. When using bar marks for timestamps, the zero-point is context-dependent, and so Vega-Lite will not try to infer it for you.

For your data, I would probably approach it as follows:

- Use a `parse` argument in your data to specify the expected format of your timestamps, as in the original question
- Use a `timeUnit` transform to manually compute a relevant zero-point for your data: here a `yearmonthdate` timeUnit works well because it strips away hours, minutes, and seconds.
- Use a `y2` encoding in your bar to specify this zero-point for your bar mark.

Put together, the result might look something like this ([Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAEqwB2A1mQIwA0UAcrALaEykACKwsAS2hgAMoWb5EYOvmjjiACyRdIAFXEChbZABYATADo2AVkgBfDlWq0GLMqe28DqXbAD2+ADNxZjAAWVhmdVx-IMhtPS8oIzNzADY2OwdqGnomVlQAZg9+QW8AYVxYAE94X0Yw-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)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Rank": 1, "Name": "David Lekuta Rudisha", "Time": "1:42.15"},
      {"Rank": 2, "Name": "Taoufik Makhloufi", "Time": "1:42.61"},
      {"Rank": 3, "Name": "Clayton Murphy", "Time": "1:42.93"},
      {"Rank": 4, "Name": "Pierre-Ambroise Bosse", "Time": "1:43.41"},
      {"Rank": 5, "Name": "Ferguson Cheruiyot Rotich", "Time": "1:43.55"},
      {"Rank": 6, "Name": "Marcin Lewandowski", "Time": "1:44.20"},
      {"Rank": 7, "Name": "Alfred Kipketer", "Time": "1:46.02"},
      {"Rank": 8, "Name": "Boris Berian", "Time": "1:46.15"}
    ],
    "format": {"parse": {"Time": "date:'%M:%S.%L'"}}
  },
  "transform": [
    {"timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "field": "Time", "as": "zeropoint"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Name", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {
      "field": "Time",
      "timeUnit": "minutessecondsmilliseconds",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": "Time"
    },
    "y2": {"field": "zeropoint", "timeUnit": "minutessecondsmilliseconds"}
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.0.0.json"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant solution ! Is there a reason why i am getting the following WARNING , [Warning] Validation: /encoding/y/timeUnit should be equal to one of the allowed values

Comment: Sometimes the schema validation is more strict than the renderer.

Comment: I have failed to sort the results based on "time" field . The following didnt help : "sort": {"field":"Time"} . Do you any suggestion how to order the results based the time field ?

Comment: You can use `"x": {"field": "Name", "type": "nominal", "sort": {"field": "Time"}}` to sort the x-axis by the time field.

Comment: I have tried several option to add tooltip in order to display the Time field. can you please advise ?   :    "tooltip": {"field": "Time", "type": "temporal"},

Comment: That should work if you want the tooltip to display the raw timestamp. If you want to display the time with the timeunit used on the y-axis, you must specify that: ``"tooltip": {"field": "Time", "type": "temporal", "timeUnit": "minutessecondsmilliseconds"}``